# Assigning returned stack object to a reference variable

Tags: c++

In the example below the function `fn()` returns a copy of the object of `class A`, In the `main()` method this copy is being assigned to a reference of `class A` type.

```
class A
{
public:
    A() { std::cout << "c'tor\n"; }
    A(A const &) { std::cout << "Copy\n"; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "d'tor\n"; }
};

A fn()
{
    A a;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    A & a = fn();
}
```

So I want to understand whether `A & a = fn();` in `main()` a safe operation to perform? It seems to be compiling OK on Visual Studio. If it is a safe operation what does `a` in `main()` really point to since the return value was created on the stack which should have unwinded once it returned from `fn()`?

Thanks